# ExcelVBA If SumA > SumB or Sum C then "G" HOW?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new to excel vba and this is what i wrote to satisfy the following condition

- sumA greater than sumB or sumC then "G"
- sumB greater than sumA or sumC then "Y"
- sumC greater than sumA or sumB then "R"

within the range of gr,yr,rr cells are numbers that I will be manually inputting.

```
Dim gr As Range
Dim yr As Range
Dim rr As Range
Dim gr1 As Long
Dim yr1 As Long
Dim rr1 As Long
Dim overallrisk As Range

Set overallrisk = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C24")
Set gr = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C30:C32").Range("C33:C35").Range("D33:D35")
Set yr = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C27:C29").Range("D30:D32").Range("E33:E35")
Set rr = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("D27:D29").Range("E27:E29").Range("E30:E32")

gr1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(gr)
yr1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(yr)
rr1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rr)

If gr1 > yr1 Or rr1 Then
    overallrisk = "G"
ElseIf yr1 > gr1 Or rr1 Then
    overallrisk = "Y"
ElseIf rr1 > yr1 Or gr1 Then
    overallrisk = "R"
End If
```

I didn't get any errors so I thought it would work but the "overallrisk" cell is still blank even though I put numbers in the range of cells.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will both clean up your code, make it more readable, and should allow it to work properly!

```
Dim gr As Range, yr As Range, rr As Range
Dim gr1 As Long, yr1 As Long, rr1 As Long
Dim overallrisk As Range
Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Sheets("Dashboard")

With wks

    Set overallrisk = .Range("C24")
    Set gr = .Range("C30:C32,C33:C35,D33:D35")
    Set yr = .Range("C27:C29,D30:D32,E33:E35")
    Set rr = .Range("D27:D29,E27:E29,E30:E32")

    gr1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(gr)
    yr1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(yr)
    rr1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rr)

    If gr1 > yr1 Or gr1 > rr1 Then
        overallrisk.Value = "G"
    ElseIf yr1 > gr1 Or yr1 > rr1 Then
        overallrisk.Value = "Y"
    ElseIf rr1 > yr1 Or rr1 > gr1 Then
        overallrisk.Value = "R"
    End If

End With
```

Comment: @user1765813 -> in addition to your `IF` statement not being accurate, the way you were calling your ranges did not seem right. I've never seen a non-contiguous range called like that. Just thought I would point out the inaccuracies so you know in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is your final `If` statement.  You have:

```
If gr1 > yr1 Or rr1 Then
```

which I believe you intend to mean:

```
If (gr1 > yr1) Or (gr1 > rr1) Then
```

Excel is looking at your conditional after the `OR`, and evaluating it as a separate statement.  You want:

```
If gr1 > yr1 Or gr1 > rr1 Then
    overallrisk = "G" 
ElseIf yr1 > gr1 Or yr1 > rr1 Then     
    overallrisk = "Y" 
ElseIf rr1 > yr1 Or rr1 > gr1 Then     
    overallrisk = "R" 
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! I've tried what you recommended but it's still blank and I can't seem to figure out why...perahps it's not adding the numbers up...?

Comment: Definitely put a breakpoint in at `gr1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(gr)`, step through the code, and see if anything gets set.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not sure what step through or breakpoint is...!

Comment: No problem; just click the row you want to start debugging at, and either press F9 or select Debug > Toggle Breakpoint (depending on your version of Excel).  Press F5 to start the code, then use F8 to step through the code.  There's more help here:  http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/debug.htm